# Share session variable over different ports in local development

Tags: django

I currently have Django on port `8000` and Angular on port `4200`.

In production they will be on the same port `80`.

Due to the ports being different the session cookies are different so the authentication fails.

How can I have these two app on different ports share one set of cookies / session?

Answer (score 0):

In production you will set the [`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) in your project settings.

If you're using [`django-cors-headers`](https://github.com/OttoYiu/django-cors-headers) in development you can just set `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` to `True` (you'll want to disable this in production) and add your frontend port to the `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` to allow requests from that origin.